# How to change whole folder from http to https

Tags: htaccess, https, mod-rewrite, apache2, magento

The `checkout/onepage` is working with HTTPS. But, why `checkout/cart` is not?

Here is fragment of the .htaccess:

```
############################################
## enable rewrites

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
# RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout\/onepage
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} checkout/
# RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^checkout/$ https://idfr.com/checkout/ [R=301,L]

############################################
```

- Apache version: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
- operating system: Windows 8.1
- indications in the log files; Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"

Comment: Are you saying that `checkout/cart` does not _redirect_ to HTTPS, or it simply does not work when accessed over HTTPS? Your current rule will not redirect `checkout/cart`, but neither will it redirect `checkout/onepage`. (?) What "indications in the log files"?

Answer (score 1):

Place in your `/checkout/` folder a htaccess with this content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

It will rewrite all requests, which aren't secure (not coming to port 443) to `https`-ed url.

**Another way**

Place at the beginning of your files onepage and cart following PHP code snippet:

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER["SERVER_PORT"] != 443) {
$redir = "Location: https://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
header($redir);
header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently");
exit();
}
?>
```

which does the same.

Answer (score 1):

I think this line might be the problem:

```
RewriteRule ^checkout/$ https://idfr.com/checkout/ [R=301,L]
        ----^     ----^
```

This line `rewites the url` if the url 'starts with' (`^`) **and** 'ends with' (`$`) the string 'checkout'. Because you have no wildcards like `*` or `.`, this line now means "literally `checkout/`, nothing else".

This means that `checkout/` will match, but `checkout/example` *will not*, because it doesn't match the rewrite rule conditions.

```
# force ssl
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/checkout
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This snippet does:

- If we are HTTP (which uses port 80)
- AND the url starts with `/checkout` (*Depending on your server, the slash might not be needed)*
- ->Redirect to https version